# FBJS and Dom Ready

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

I want to know how can I use `$(document).ready` or something like that in FBJS for Facebook applications. I tried `$(document).ready` but it ain't working. Also I couldn't find any associated document...

Comment: i use FBC and FBJS with jQuery and they work together nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the jQuery code first?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By saying you are trying to use FBJS it implies you are building an FBML app.  Is that correct?  You can't use Jquery with an FBML app.  If you want to use jquery you need to build an Iframe app or external connect app...in which case you can't use FBJS.

Or are you trying to use the Facebook javascript client library (which is not FBJS)?